# recreate list of installed packages from mounted HD 11.10 into 12.04?

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, apt, package-management, backup

I want to recreate the list of installed packages I had in my 11.10 installation into my new 12.04 one. I updated to 12.04 at the same time I bought a new HD, so I can mount the old HD where the old 11.10 system was installed, read the list of installed packages in 11.10 *somewhere*, and do an `apt-get install` for each of them. How can I produce the list of installed packages from the mounted HD where my 11.10 was installed?

I can't run commands on the 11.10 system since I have already changed the HD, but if the list is somewhere in `/var/cache/apt/archives` I can look at the mounted HD, that would be the solution for me.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the above question. This question asks how to get a list of a "mounted" drive not current running OS. This question must be answered using CHRoot not the method in the other question. Please re-open this question so I may answer it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

sudo dpkg --get-selections.

If you want these packages to be installed on 12.04, do the following

1. On your 11.10

sudo dpkg --get-selections "*" > packages

1. Transfer the file 'packages' to 12.04 and do

sudo apt-get update

sudo dpkg --set-selections < packages

sudo apt-get -u dselect-upgrade

You can refer to this : http://sosaysharis.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/upgrading-to-ubuntu-12-04-the-way-i-did-it/

Comment: I can't change the HD again. I would like to get that list from the mounted HD.

Comment: Well your apt's cache will have quite a lot of the packages you have installed. But I'm not sure if that will have all of them. You can find it at /var/cache/apt/archives